# How to add same product with different price for multiple cities

Tags: product, configurable-product, multistore, store-view, products-management

I am creating a multi store Magento website in 1.9.2.4, feel free to see the demo [Demo of My site](http://115.118.113.154/magedata)

I also added few products(Grocery & Frozen) under different cities - Jamnagar, Ahmedabad, Surat.

[image: Manage Store Screen Shot]

Prices of the products price & taxes (if applicable)vary from city to city, now I'm in panic thinking that for same product I have to create each of them with  different price and taxes for each each respectively.

My question is - What I am thinking is correct, is this only way to add products for each cities, or is there any easy or convenient method preset in Magento. Kindly suggest the best option.

Comment: @ Amit Deb : may i know how could you maintain your inventory for multiple stores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to change your pricing scope to be Website or lower.  You can do this by going to System -> Configuration -> Catalog then look under the Pricing section.  Once you have the pricing scope set, just edit the product and choose a different store view to modify the pricing for that view.

Comment: Your reply is like a glass of cold water in middle of Sahara Desert. Thank you. Is there any way to store these data for 782 products in 1 shot, say for example Import/Export process.

Comment: Use the Import / Export Data Profiles or use Magmi tool, it does an amazing job. I prefer Magmi.

Comment: @Hashid : Magmi is only for import, do u know about any export method.